# CakePHP sort by one column then another column

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination

Is there anyway in CakePHP to sort pagination by multiple column?
I have this code

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'limit' => $limit,
        'fields' => array(
                    'DISTINCT (Project.id) AS id',
                    'Project.project_type_id',
                    'Project.contact_id',
                    'Project.company_id',
                    'Project.due_date',
                    'Project.subject',
                    'Project.description',
                    'Project.created',
                    'Project.creator',
                    'Project.project_status_id',
                    'Project.modified',
                    'Project.complete_date',
                    ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'project_reminder_users',
                'alias' => 'ProjectReminderUser',
                'type' => 'left',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Project.id=ProjectReminderUser.project_id',
                ),
            ),
        ),              
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
            'Project.creator' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'),
        ),
        'order' => 'Project.project_status_id',
    )
);

$this->set('groupTasks', $this->paginate('Project'));
```

and it will result in something like this with order of Project.project_status_id

```
Task Name   |   Due Date    |   Status  |
Task 1      |   -           |   Open    |
Task 2      |   2/15/2014   |   Open    |
Task 3      |   2/28/2014   |   Open    |
Task 4      |   2/20/2014   |   Open    |
Task 5      |   -           |   Open    |
Task 6      |   -           |   Open    |
Task 7      |   -           |   Closed  |
Task 8      |   -           |   Closed  |
```

Is there anyway so it can sort by Status then by due date so it will look like this

```
Task Name   |   Due Date    |   Status  |
Task 1      |   -           |   Open    |
Task 5      |   -           |   Open    |
Task 6      |   -           |   Open    |
Task 2      |   2/15/2014   |   Open    |
Task 4      |   2/20/2014   |   Open    |
Task 3      |   2/28/2014   |   Open    |
Task 7      |   -           |   Closed  |
Task 8      |   -           |   Closed  |
```

and maybe after that sort by task name..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'order' => array(
    'first_field' => 'DESC',
    'second_field' => 'ASC'
)
```

Comment: this is working but only once (when it first time show up), but once user click say status to sort so 'Closed' at the top, this does not maintain the order anymore, only maintain one of it. any way to fix this? e.g: if user click status, it will order so "closed" show on the first row, if user reclick status again, it should go back to where it supposed to be, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the html table to render the result. Then to implement the stated functionality one possible solution is to send an ajax request on the click of column header. In the controller, you can save the previous requested sorted column into ajax. And during the next sort request, check if there is any other previously sort request received or not.

If you can use the jquery plugin, [this link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) will help you to sort multiple column.

Answer (score 0):

Easy insert 'paramType' => 'querystring', Show Code Example:

```
$this->paginate = array(
'conditions' => $conditions,
'order' => array(
    'Post.name' => 'ASC',
    'Post.created' => 'DESC',

),
'paramType' => 'querystring',

);

$this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
```

Saludos :-)